# Difference in usage of darken function

Tags: less

I was using Less and I have come across a situation where

```
darken(darken(#ffffff, 3), 5)    //darken(#ffffff, 3) return #f7f7f7
```

returns #ebebeb. But,

```
darken(#f7f7f7, 5)
```

returns #eaeaea

aren't those usages same? Why does the output differ?

Comment: Because this is floating point arithmetics (result of `darken(#ffffff, 3)` is not *exactly* `#f7f7f7` - it's just a rounded representation. In other words, things like `round(round(x*3)*5)` and `round(x*3*5)` are expected to produce different (by +/-1) results depending on `x`).

Comment: [Demo](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22foo%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%40c%3A%20darken(%23fff%2C%203%25)%3B%5Cn%20%20%20foo%3A%20green(%40c)%3B%20%2F%2F%20I'm%20not%20%23f7%5Cn%7D%22%7D).

Comment: Thank you @seven-phases-max